# Is it possible to toggle slow animation for a spring animation

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, uikit-dynamics

In iOS simulator there is an option for turning on slow animations. I see that if I create an animation with UIView's `animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:` this debug option does not work. Has anyone noticed this behaviour?

Comment: Have a button to selectively increase the duration parameter in the animation block :)